# How to remotely connect to a mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have mongodb installed in lab computer and I have written the php code to connect to it.

```
 <?php

     $server="mongodb://172.27.20.188:27017/test_database";
     $m=new Mongo($server);
     if ($m->connected)
        {echo "succesful";}
     else
        {echo "failed";}
?>
```

When I am running it on local machine command line, it is showing me successful. But when I try to access it from another machine browser, the page is not working. I have also tried commenting out the line bind_ip in mongodb.conf.

Comment: If you're running the mongo DB server on your local computer, are you making sure to port forward port 27017 when you try to access it from a remote computer?

Comment: @KyleGoodale in mongod.conf the port is 27017. I dont understand what you meant. This is the first time I am working on this. sorry, but can you please explain it to me? Then I can check it out

Comment: If you are hosting the database on a local computer and need to access it from a remote computer you need to setup port forwarding on your router. This tells your router to send incoming connections on port 27017 to your computer that you have Mongodb on.

Comment: Offtopic: i advise you to check psr coding standart recommendations http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/